# android json parsing keeps on loading

Tags: java, android, json

I am not new to android platform, i have parsed many json pages before, but one link is creating problem. I am using following function to return the json object. The program stops at reader.readline() and loading does not stop.

```
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(new HttpGet(url));
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
        {
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Unsupported Encoding");
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Client Protocol");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("IO");
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);

        }
        is.close();
        jsonStr = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error here");
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jObj;

}
```

can any one suggest something?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that this is caused by the server not finishing the response in your case. Try to isolate that using "curl" as a client first.

Also there is an easier way to fetch body into String if you use EntitUtils like this:

```
EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

You can also specify encoding as second parameter.
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html

Comment: i have tried the entityutils also.the url is working fine in the browser but there is something wrong in the program i think, cause when i store the json in string it works correctly but do not get from  the link